# track sessions in PHP - am I doing it right?

Tags: php, session

I am a first time php developer;

I track sessions this way:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']->iduser)) {
    die('Access denied. <br><a href=login.php>Please login</a>');
}
```

is that correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes it seem as though you're storing an entire object into a session-variable which would not be a great idea (could take up a lot of space, stores way too much data, is it even possible without serialize/unserialize?).

Also, if your user hasn't been authenticated yet your code would throw a warning because `$_SESSION['user']` isn't set yet - so by checking for `$_SESSION['user']->iduser`, you'd be checking for a property/value on a null object. Your code should check `if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {`, and then possibly validate on that.

I would recommend just storing the "essentials" in the session such as the user's ID/username and encrypted password. Then, during each page load you re-validate the information against the database. It's an extra query on each page-load, but it's worth it (in my opinion).

Comment: but in general, is this correct way of using sessions? Because it is weird, but my chrome saying that I am using cookies. What is the most current way of using sessions?

Comment: @Andrew When you use a session in PHP, it sends a cookie to the user's browser, `PHPSESSID`. The user's browser will send this cookie back to the server during every request - that way the server will know what session the current user is using. So, yeah, in that respect - you're using them correctly (as far as I can tell from the sample-code you provided)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really asking this question:

> Is it OK to identify a user by their unique ID in the session?

My Answer: Yes. This is frequently how it's done and will work fine in the session. I wouldn't do it this way using cookies, but in the server-side session storage it should be fine.